# How to turn a string into int with more than 1 digit in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, integer

This is my code

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < form.size(); i++)
    if (isdigit(form[i]))
       {
            value=form[i] - '0';
            operand.push(value)   //this is a stack
       }
```

but it only works when you have an int of 1 digit, lets say the form string has 1, it works just fine, but when the string gets 10, it won't work because it will set value first into 1 then into 0 and wont get the number 10, is there a way to do it inside the for loop? I can't use atoi because sometimes the string can have characters like '/' or '*' and i need to place them in another stack. i would like to know if there is a way to get the value variable to contain the integer 10.
I have to save the ints and the operators from the string. Getting the number 1 and then 0 isn't the problem, the problem is converting the 2 ints into one multi-digit int 1 0 into 10, 2 5 into 25 and so on.

Comment: Yes, there's a way but you have to do more work. Basically you need to stop processing the string one character at a time. For instance when you find a digit, you could then scan forward in the string to see how many digits you have got and then convert them all at once and then push the combined value on the stack.

Comment: Do you have to implement the algorithm? Or can you use a standard library?

Comment: If this is an assignment, you're probably going to have to build a character-by-character parser.

Comment: @john that sounds a whole lot like what using an `std::stringstream` would give you for free.

Comment: Welll, if `atoi()` doesn't work for you bump it up a notch and use `strtol()`: aside from the value returned it updates an end pointer so you know where things left up if the third argument is non-`nullptr` (you'll also need to pass the base a third argument).

Comment: @scohe001 You could use a `stringstream` in combination with `istream::peek` to see what the next character is without consuming it. That might work. Perhaps debateable if it's more or less work though.

Comment: @john the extraction operator (`>>`) should already handle all of that for you, no? Just run the string through some regex first that replaces non-integer chars with spaces and you're set.

Comment: @scohe001 I think it's pretty clear that the OP is writing an expression parser, so the non digit characters can't just be discarded.

Comment: Then it's even easier @john. Extraction operator will give you the full integer and stop at the operator for you to read into a char, and then you're good to read in another int again. But if OP is indeed doing something more intricate than just reading all the ints in, that should really be stated in the question so we're not left to guess.

Comment: Yes, but you have to know whether the next character to be read is a digit or not, which is why I suggested using `istream::peek`

Comment: @john uhm, that's interesting, but can lead to some problems, like if finding a digit in the last place of the string you would try to look for something forward that doesn't exist and would get a segmentation fault, i hope that isn't the only way

Comment: @john we're both making different guesses at the contents of the string and its purpose. I don't think this conversation will be productive until OP gives us more information on the constraints around what the string is guaranteed to look like.

Comment: @HenriqueKrever If you use `istream::peek` and there is nothing left to read then you will just get a return of `EOF` for end of file. It won't crash.

Comment: i think the bigger problem would be how to convert 2 separate ints into one like getting 1 and 0 is easy, the problem would be how to make them become 10. @scohe001

Comment: @Henrique please [edit] your question to specify what the string will look like and what you actually want out of it. Do you just want a list of int's while you discard any non integer characters? Or do you want to read in int's and operators? If you just want to read a single multi-digit int, that's simple: https://ideone.com/O3BA4L

Comment: @scohe001 i need to save the ints and operators from the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0, temp = 0; i <= form.size(); i++) {
  if (i == form.size() || !isdigit(form[i])) {
    operand.push(temp);
    temp = 0;
  }
  temp = (temp * 10) + form[i] - '0';
}
```